# How to convert message.text to string and save it to database. How to download photo by telegram bot. TelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, database, sqlite, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I want save photo and add name of file and text of message to database.(Also in this database I have status of request and user, how make request, this 2 columns works ok)

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE main (
    id     STRING,
    owner  STRING,
    status STRING,
    photo  STRING
);
```

Full code:

```
import telebot as tl
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("D:/Promo_Bot/codes.db", check_same_thread=False)
cur = conn.cursor()
bot = tl.TeleBot("1875698946:AAGKlLTNEjaJQAz4VOj4Pc3Jej3A1tj-WjY")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Запрос отправлен на модерацию")
    link = message.text
    with open(link, "wb") as save_file:
        save_file.write(bot.download_file(bot.get_file(message.photo[0].file_id).file_path))
        data = [(message.text, str(message.from_user.username), 'wait', link)]
    cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO main
                VALUES (?, ?, ?,
                ?)""", data)
    conn.commit()
@bot.message_handler()
def no(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Отправте номер на чеке и фото одним сообщение")


bot.polling()
```

Problem:
My program save None to 1st column and None.jfif to 4th column.
[SQLite Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zel3H.png)

Thanks

Comment: BTW, you posted your bot token, so you should revoke that with @BotFather …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing `message.text` into the database inside the `photo` function. However, that function is only triggered for messages containing a `photo`. When the `message` contains a photo, `message.text is None`. Any caption the photo might have will be in `message.caption`.